# how to set mutiple values for multi select2 tag element in grails <g:select using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, jquery-select2

> i am trying to set multiple option value in  tag in grails
>   using angularjs. Here the initial select option has loaded through grails.actually here i have work in migrate to angularjs. I
>   have mention code below.and also i am new to grails part..so i don't know how to use angularjs in grails..Can any one give ideas

**My gsp select Tag:**

```
<g:select id="fromLogicalDockGroupId" multiple="true"  name="fromLogicalDockGroupId" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" from="${dockGroups}" class="select2 multiSelect" ng-model="taskCreateForm.fromLogicalDockGroupId" />
```

**Now apply selected value from controller**

```
$scope.taskCreateForm=data;
```

**data object value for apply to**

```
fromLogicalDockGroupId: Array[2]
0: "2"
1: "1"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a grails specific problem, either you have to do it using angular or some javascript code will do it for you.

g:select takes the value as an argument which we will be shown selected.

Comment: Yes, u r correct..thanks bro..$('#fromLogicalDockGroupId').select2('val',data.fromLogicalDockGroupId);